# Thymeleaf | Is TemplateEngine.process thread-safe operation?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, thymeleaf

I use `thymeleaf` template engine to build request to SOAP service. The class that perform sending looks like this:

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;

import org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate;

import org.thymeleaf.*;
import org.thymeleaf.context.*;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.*;

public class SomeService 
{
    private final TemplateEngine templateEngine;
    private final WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate;

    public RetrieveServiceThymeleafBased() {
        webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();
        webServiceTemplate.setDefaultUri("http://some.path/to/soap/service");

        ITemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
    }

    public void sendMessage(String orderNumber) {
        Context params = new Context();
        params.setVariable("CreateDateTime", new Date());
        params.setVariable("GUID", UUID.randomUUID());
        String xmlContent = templateEngine.process("template.xml", params);

        StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlContent));
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
        webServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(source, result);
    }
}
```

I know that `webServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult` - is thread-safe operation, But I can't find this kind of information about `templateEngine.process`

Question : Is `templateEngine.process` a thread-safe operation or not

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, it is. `TemplateEngine` objects are designed to be used in highly-concurrent environments without issues (I hope! ;)).

Disclaimer, per StackOverflow rules: I'm Thymeleaf's author.

Comment: Nice to hear it, but, as it's a pretty complex intertwining of Thymeleaf and Spring, things happen - [Thymeleaf concurency error...](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring/issues/83).... So, be cautious

Comment: Have a small comment in the javadoc. That was the first information i was looking for thread-safe / concurrent. It is mentioned that instantiation is expensive. Next thought is then 'use a singleton' next thought is then is it 'thread safety'...